# strtok не разбивает строку по пробелам

Tags: c++, строки

Есть такой код
мне нужно что-бы он разбивал строку на слова но он останавливается на первом пробеле

```
SetConsoleCP(1251);
SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
int n,n2;
char str[80], str3[80];
scanf("%s", str);
str3[0] = '\0';
char * pch = strtok(str, ",\n");
while( pch != NULL)
{
    cout << pch << endl;
    pch = strtok(NULL, ",\n");
}

system("pause");
return 0;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция `scanf` прекращает чтение, когда встречается символ "белого" пробела. Используйте вместо нее по крайней мере функцию `fgets`. Например,

```
fgtes( str, sizeof( str ), stdin );
```

Эта функция может добавить символ новой строки в конец символьного массива.

А еще лучше использовать стандартные C++ функции, работающие с потоками. Например,

```
std::cin.getline( str, sizeof( str ) );
```